# JBoss Profiler not showing up in JBoss

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, profiling, jboss5.x

I am trying to run JBoss Profiler(jboss-profiler-2.0.0.Beta5) on my JBoss AS5.0 for a web application made on RF3.3

I followed all the steps mentioned in the JBoss profiler user guide:-

```
Copy jboss-profiler.jar to jbossas/bin
• Copy jboss-profiler.properties to jbossas/bin
• Edit jboss-profiler.properties in jbossas/bin to include the classes to be profiled
• Copy jboss-profiler-plugins.jar to jbossas/bin
• Edit run.conf (Unix) or run.bat (Windows) in jbossas/bin to include JBoss Profiler in JAVA_OPTS
• Copy jboss-profiler.sar to jbossas/server/<conf>/deploy
• Boot application server
Include the following in JAVA_OPTS
-javaagent:jboss-profiler.jar -Djboss-profiler.properties=jboss-profiler.properties
```

Post this I started my JBoss AS.The MBean is getting registered and I am able to see the MBean also..During startup I observe that Profiler is taking entry as IP(say 10.10.10.10) and port 5400 whereas I had specified 8080 in the jboss-profiler.props file.

Now when I navigate to 10.10.10.10:8080/jboss-profiler I get 404 page not found.
When I navigate to 10.10.10.10:5400/jboss-profiler I get exception as:-

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.createServerSocketWrapper(ServerThread.java:907)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:489)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:230)

Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 47455420

        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:782)

        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)

        at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.<init>(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:97)

        at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.createInput(JavaSerializationManager.java:54)

        at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.getMarshallingStream(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:7

        at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.getMarshallingStream(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:5

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ClientSocketWrapper.createInputStream(ClientSocketWrapper.java:179)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ClientSocketWrapper.createStreams(ClientSocketWrapper.java:162)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ClientSocketWrapper.<init>(ClientSocketWrapper.java:66)

        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerSocketWrapper.<init>(ServerSocketWrapper.java:46)

        ... 7 more
```

When I tried running the command java -jar jboss-profiler-client.jar from commandprompt it says

```
org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [socket://localhost:5400/]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:579)
        at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:536)
        at org.jboss.profiler.client.cmd.Client.main(Client.java:281)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.createSocket(SocketClientInvoker.java:192)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.getConnection(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:827)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:569)
        ... 5 more
```

Can anyone PLEASE GUIDE ME HOW TO SETUP PROFILER....
The same doubt is also posted on JBoss forum.
https://community.jboss.org/message/743228#743228

Comment: Check any firewalls stopping your connection as well as port is open or not. It is connection refused, so I guess either Firewall (or) port may be culprit.

Comment: Firewall is surely not an issue as I found that the same thing is happening on linux machine also which is on public IP>